# MySQL & CodeIgniter 3 : Error too many connection

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

So I have a little problem here, I'm using CodeIgniter 3.
Sometimes when I try to access my website.
It comes to an error too many connection.

This is my database.php

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'testing',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Any correct code to solve this problem ?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: you should close connect to end of all the pages

Answer (score 0):

Off the `mysql.allow_persistent` because if it is on. Then it create connections again and again

```
//Set mysql.allow_persistent ON to Off
mysql.allow_persistent = Off
```

> Note : If Persistent connections is on, that do not close when the
>   execution of your script ends

Also Read [Too many connections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/too-many-connections.html)

Comment: So.. I should tell the server administrator to set off the mysql.allow_persistent ?

Comment: yes or you can also set in your mysql.ini file if you have permission to access it!!

Answer (score 0):

I was recently stumped by the fact that one of my controllers was maxing out connections to the database. Adding in some debug logging revealed that it was creating a new connection for every single query, and holding them open, so they were rapidly exhausted. None of my other controllers did this, they all used a single connection per request.

After much head-scratching, what eventually solved it was adding `$this->load->library('session');` to the controller's constructor, after `$this->load->database();`. All my other controllers had that, but this particular controller didn't do any session-related stuff so I hadn't bothered with it. But for some reason it seems to be necessary to load it in order to use a single database connection for the lifetime of the request.

This was in CodeIgniter 2.x, but much of the 3.x code is the same, so it might apply there too.